# $.get seemingly not getting called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I am using a simple jquery get to just load a static file.
The particular function call has two seperate gets for two seperate files:

```
DataController.prototype.init = function(){
    //load config
    $.get('files/config.json', function(c) {
        master.config = c;
        master.setConfigs();
    });
    //load data file
    $.get('files/outfile.geojson', function(geo) {

        var data = JSON.parse(geo);
        var area = new AreaData();

        var s = data.features[0];

        area.areaId = s.properties.areaId;
        area.name = s.properties.name;

        this.temp = data;

        master.addInitialState(area, s.geometry);
   });
}
```

When I run the code, the second get request is performed as expected, the file is loaded, its data obtained, etc.

The first get however never runs at all. I've tried running it in both chrome and edge to no avail. I know its asynch so it may not be called immediately but when I ran it with a breakpoint inside that get it simply never reached it.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`, to avoid having to `JSON.parse` the result yourself (which you forgot to do in the first one). How do you know it does not run? You don't see the request going out in Chrome's Network tab? No errors in the console? Always use your browser's developer tools, that's going to save you a lot of time, too many beginners don't know about the dev tools

Comment: What does `console.log(c)` says?

Comment: Also, does your 2nd "get" depend on the 1st one? Such as the "configs"? If so, nest your 2nd one in the 1st. ... But per @blex comment will solve your immediate issue

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues...status, what gets returned etc

Comment: I switched it to getJSON because it makes sense but it wasn't the solution. Using console.log(c) does nothing. The two requests are completely unrelated. I've been using the dev tools extensively, I can't find anything using them. The network tab does show something regarding config.json, seems like the completed request but I have no reason to believe that the request actually went through based on everything else. The only errors I'm getting in the console are ones saying that config is undefined from elsewhere in the program that needs it.

Comment: Did you look on the network tab?

Comment: Yes, there is an entry for config.json. It has an OK status. The inside of that request is still never called based on the breakpoint never being reached in the debugger and a print statement inside never being called either

Comment: Reading the docs for jquery.getJSON I saw that it will fail silently if there is an error in the json file. I just went back through the config.json file and found an error, fixing it solved the issue. Seems like terrible design that it fails silently, I'm sure someone else can tell me why its actually the best

Comment: There is a `fail()` method you can chain to it

Answer (score 0):

jquery get requests fail silently when there is an error in the JSON file.
Fixing the error fixed my problems.

I don't know why they chose to make it fail silently when they designed it but thats how it is.

Comment: Directly from the official jquery docs:
"As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently"
obviously using an explicit fail() method will no longer be silent but if you don't include that then it is completely silent